# Ruby 1.9 parse hash into an html table

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a Ruby hash, for example:

```
{"monkeys"=> {"hamburgers" => ["love", "eat"],
              "boulders" => ["hate", "throw"]},
 "stonemasons" => {"boulders" = > ["love", "use"],
                   "vandals" => ["hate", "sue"]}
}
```

It can have almost any level (I can put hashes inside hashes any number of times) of depth. It always has arrays as end values.

How can I parse it into an HTML table like the one below without using Rails and, preferably, using only the Standard library?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">monkeys</th>
    <th>hamburgers</th>
    <td>love</td>
    <td>eat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>boulders</th>
    <td>hate</td>
    <td>throw</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">stonemasons</th>
    <th>boulders</th>
    <td>love</td>
    <td>use</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>vandals</th>
    <td>hate</td>
    <td>sue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hope this link will help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588196/turn-a-ruby-hash-into-html-list

Comment: It helped, to a certain extent, but the main issues are with: 1) counting colspans; 2) finding new tr's and placing them appropriately.

Comment: It seems weird that you want some `tr` with 2 `th` and 2 `td` and others have only a `th` and 2 `td`. Are you sure you don't need to use `rowspan` instead of `colspan` for the resulting table?

Comment: You're right, I do need rowspans, not colspans. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: Please, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2635415/1868738 hope that link will help you.

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

```
h = {"monkeys"     => {"hamburgers" => ["love", "eat"],
                       "boulders"   => ["hate", "throw"]},
     "stonemasons" => {"boulders"   => ["love", "use"],
                       "vandals"    => ["hate", "sue"]}}


def parse_data(html, data, new_line = true)

  klass = data.class

  # Use the class to know if we need to create TH or TD
  case
  when klass == Hash
    data.each do |key, value|

      # Start a new row
      if new_line
        html << '<tr>'
        new_line = false
      end

      # Check if we need to use a rowspan
      if value.class == Array || value.count == 1
        html << "<th>#{key}</th>"
      else
        html << "<th rowspan=\"#{value.count}\">#{key}</th>"
      end

      # Parse the content of the hash (recursive)
      html, new_line = parse_data(html, value, new_line)
    end
  when klass = Array
    data.each do |item|
      html << "<td>#{item}</td>"
    end

    # We end the row and flag that we need to start a new one
    # if there is anymore data
    html << '</tr>'
    new_line = true
  end

  return html, new_line
end

html = '<table>'
html, new_line = parse_data(html, h)
html << '</table>'

puts html
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">monkeys</th>
    <th>hamburgers</th>
    <td>love</td>
    <td>eat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>boulders</th>
    <td>hate</td>
    <td>throw</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">stonemasons</th>
    <th>boulders</th>
    <td>love</td>
    <td>use</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>vandals</th>
    <td>hate</td>
    <td>sue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks! But will it work if I have two hashes like h as values in another hash? Like, `k={"in USA"=>h, "in UK" => h}` ?

Comment: It should. It parses the hash structure until it finds an array then it ends the row and start with a new one. So you can have any number of hashes nested as long as the deeper nested elements are arrays.

Comment: I tried it now and sadly, it doesn't. It gives both "in USA" and "in UK" rowspans of 2 whereas they should be both 4 (the number of end values)

Comment: Looking a bit deeper at it, it is really more complex that I thought initially: you need to keep the keys in order for each line and then update the rowspan afterwards when you know the depth of each branch. If I have some time next week I'll try to have a go at it. Sorry if I misled you.