# Convert Nested hashes in Ruby into a table format

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a nested hash in ruby:

```
{"Table1"=>{"Acct type"=>{"Expected"=>"ACC", "Actual"=>"ACC"}, "Seq No"=>{"Expected"=>"100.0", "Actual"=>#<BigDecimal:56d0b28,'0.1E3',9(18)>}, "Class"=>{"Expected"=>"AC", "Actual"=>"AC"}}, "Table 2"=>{"Date"=>{"Expected"=>"20140606", "Actual"=>"20130606"}}}
```

I need to display the above nested hash in a table format -

```
Table   Field   Expected Value  Actual Value
Table 1 Acct type  ACC            ACC
Table 1 Seq No     100.0          100.0
Table 1 Class      AC             AC
Table 2 Date       20140606       20130606
```

Any suggestions/pointers would be really helpful. I have tried using 'tableprint' and 'text-table' gems but couldn't get the desired result. The above data was fetched from DB2 tables using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Please format and tag your question correctly.  What language are you using?

Comment: U should probably check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534040/ruby-1-9-parse-hash-into-an-html-table

Comment: Your data seems to off. There is a `#` in there! Please check and try to get better formatting.

Comment: # in data - That's how ActiveRecord fetches data from DB2 if the datatype is Int or Big Decimal

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
x = {
  "Table1"=>{
    "Acct type"=>{"Expected"=>"ACC", "Actual"=>"ACC"},
    "Seq No"=>{"Expected"=>"100.0", "Actual"=> 100.00},
    "Class"=>{"Expected"=>"AC", "Actual"=>"AC"}
  },
  "Table 2"=>{
    "Date"=> {"Expected"=>"20140606",
              "Actual"=>"20130606"}}}

def table_row(row_name, row_values)
  [row_name, row_values["Expected"], row_values["Actual"]]
end

def table_rows(table_hash)
  table_hash.map do |field_name, field_values|
    table_row(field_name, field_values)
  end
end

def widest_string_lengths(visual_table)
  table_columns_count = visual_table.first.size - 1
  0.upto(table_columns_count).map do |index|
    columns = visual_table.map { |row| row[index].to_s }
    columns.max_by(&:length).length + 2
  end
end

def aligned_visual_table(visual_table)
  widest_string_items = widest_string_lengths(visual_table)

  visual_table.map do |row|
    row.each_with_index.map do |cell, index|
      cell.to_s.ljust(widest_string_items[index] + 2)
    end
  end
end

table_headers = ['Table', 'Field', 'Value', 'Actual Value']

# This just turns the hash to array of arrays
visual_table = x.map do |table_name, table_hash|
   table_rows(table_hash).map do |table_rows|
      table_rows.insert(0, table_name)
    end
end.flatten(1).insert(0, table_headers)

puts "*********"
puts aligned_visual_table(visual_table).map(&:join).join("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You example suggests there are unspecified parameters affecting the appearance of the table. For example, the column labels "Table" and "Field" are left-adjusted, whereas "Expected Value" and "Actual Value" are not.  Also, "Expected Value" overlaps "Acct type". Below I suggest how you might construct the table, but I've made compromises: left-adjusting all column labels and not overlapping vertically.

**Code**

```
def print_table(h, column_labels_and_spacing, table_label)
  column_labels = column_labels_and_spacing.map(&:first)
  column_spacing = column_labels_and_spacing[0..-2].map(&:last) << 0
  rows = h.map { |k,f|
            [table_label[k]].product(f.map { |field, g|
              [[field, g.values.map(&:to_s)].flatten] }) }
          .flat_map { |e| e.map(&:flatten) }.unshift(column_labels)
  column_widths = rows.transpose.map { |c| c.max_by(&:size).size }
                      .zip(column_spacing).map { |a,b| a+b }
  rows.each do |row|
    row.zip(column_widths).each { |s, width| print s.ljust(width) }
    puts
  end  
end
```

**Example**

*Input*

```
h = {"Table1"=>
      {"Acct type"=>{"Expected"=>"ACC",   "Actual"=>"ACC"},
       "Seq No"   =>{"Expected"=>"100.0", "Actual"=>100},
       "Class"    =>{"Expected"=>"AC",    "Actual"=>"AC"}},
     "Table 2"=>
       {"Date"    =>{"Expected"=>"20140606",  "Actual"=>"20130606"}}}

column_labels_and_spacing = [["Table", 1], ["Field", 2],
                             ["Expected", 3], ["Actual"]]
table_label = { "Table1"=>"Table 1", "Table 2"=>"Table 2" }
```

To simplify the explanation I converted the `BigDecimal` value to a `Fixnum`.

*Invoke method*

```
print_table(h, column_labels_and_spacing, table_label)
  #->  Table   Field      Expected   Actual  
  #    Table 1 Acct type  ACC        ACC     
  #    Table 1 Seq No     100.0      100     
  #    Table 1 Class      AC         AC      
  #    Table 2 Date       20140606   20130606
```

**Explanation**

For the above example:

```
column_labels = column_labels_and_spacing.map(&:first)
  #=> ["Table", "Field", "Expected", "Actual"] 
column_spacing = column_labels_and_spacing[0..-2].map(&:last) << 0
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 0] 

a = h.map { |k,f|
       [table_label[k]].product(f.map { |field, g|
         [[field, g.values.map(&:to_s)].flatten] }) }
  # => [[["Table 1", [["Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"]]],
  #      ["Table 1", [["Seq No", "100.0", "100"]]],
  #      ["Table 1", [["Class", "AC", "AC"]]]],
  #    [["Table 2", [["Date", "20140606", "20130606"]]]]]
```

To see how `a` is calculated, consider the first key-value pair of `h` passed to the block<sup>1</sup>, the key being assigned to the block variable `k` and the value assigned to `f`:

```
  k = "Table1"
  f = { "Acct type"=>{ "Expected"=>"ACC", "Actual"=>"ACC" } }
```

The block then performs the following calculations:

```
  b = f.map { |field, g| [[field, g.values.map(&:to_s)].flatten] }
    # => [["Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"]]

  c = ["Table 1"].product([[["Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"]]])
    #=> [["Table 1", [["Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"]]]]

  d = c.flatten
    #=> ["Table 1", "Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"]
```

Now let's carry on, having computed `a`. Compute the rows of the body of the table:

```
  e = a.flat_map { |e| e.map(&:flatten) }
    #=> [["Table 1", "Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"],
    #    ["Table 1", "Seq No", "100.0", "100"],
    #    ["Table 1", "Class", "AC", "AC"],
    #    ["Table 2", "Date", "20140606", "20130606"]]
```

and then add the column labels:

```
  rows = e.unshift(column_labels)
    #=> [["Table", "Field", "Expected", "Actual"],
    #    ["Table 1", "Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"],
    #    ["Table 1", "Seq No", "100.0", "100"],
    #    ["Table 1", "Class", "AC", "AC"],
    #    ["Table 2", "Date", "20140606", "20130606"]]
```

Next, compute column widths:

```
f = rows.transpose
  #=> [["Table", "Table 1", "Table 1", "Table 1", "Table 2"],
  #    ["Field", "Acct type", "Seq No", "Class", "Date"],
  #    ["Expected", "ACC", "100.0", "AC", "20140606"],
  #    ["Actual", "ACC", "100", "AC", "20130606"]] 

g = f.map { |c| c.max_by(&:size).size }
  #=> [7, 9, 8, 8] 

i = g.zip(column_spacing)
  # => [[7, 1], [9, 2], [8, 3], [8, 0]]

column_widths = i.map { |a,b| a+b }
  #=> [8, 11, 11, 8]

rows.each do |row|
  row.zip(column_widths).each { |s, width| print s.ljust(width) }
  puts
end
```

Consider the printing of the second row of the table (the first row after the column labels):

```
row = ["Table 1", "Acct type", "ACC", "ACC"]
row.zip(column_widths)
  # => [["Table 1", 8], ["Acct type", 11], ["ACC", 11], ["ACC", 8]]
```

The first field is printed:

```
s = "Table 1"
width = 8
print s.ljust(width); puts ?:
  #Table 1 :
```

where I printed the colon just to show the field width. Other fields are printed similarly.

<sup>1</sup> Ruby 1.9+ is required to know which key-value pair is passed to the block first.